# changing arrow head properties of ArrowHelper class Threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using the arrow helper class, I found this example http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Helpers.html and I was able to get the arrow working. However my arrowhead is much larger than I would like it to be, I currently have this code

```
var direction = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(secondVector, firstVector).normalize();
var arrow = new THREE.ArrowHelper(direction, firstVector, computeDistance(node1, node2) - 32, co);
bigObject.add(arrow);
```

the arrow starts at firstVector and points to `secondVector

is there a way to change the size or any properties of how the arrow head gets drawn (eg stroke weight, arrowhead location, etc.) ? I didn't see anything that looked promising in the documentation.

thank you for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good question, but the answer is 'No'. The head of the arrow scales with the arrow's length.

Your only solution is to create your own custom `ArrowHelper`.

three.js r.63

EDIT: This feature has been added to the dev branch three.js r.64dev.

```
var arrow = new THREE.ArrowHelper( dir, origin, length, hex, headLength, headWidth );
```